# Hide/Remove "Recently viewed Accounts" list view

Tags: list-view, tab

Is it possible to hide the recently viewed accounts list view (drop down) from my users? I am referring to the "Recently viewed accounts" view in the picklist on the account landing page.

[image: recently viewed accounts]

It really confuses them, as this list view doesn't even seem to be ordered in order of recently viewed items?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add detail around where this view is displayed so we can better assist you.

Answer (score 4):

Without writing Visualforce to override both the Accounts Home tab and the Accounts List View, it is impossible to hide or delete this list view, as it has a standard sharing model, cannot be edited, and cannot be deleted. It has a default sort order of Account Name, which is why it doesn't show accounts in the most recently viewed order. It would just be easier to include this system view when training the users about the system.

Comment: If it cannot be ordered by recently viewed items,  I ask myself why it is called recently viewed accounts.  Shame,  very confusing.  Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: This is commonly one of the biggest hurdles for users. I cannot count the number of times users say they cannot find records, only to have to tell them to click go or select a list view. They just do not get that the first thing they come to when clicking a tab is not all of their accounts, etc. Really a pain

Answer (score 4):

You cannot customize the standard tab in that way. However, you could create a custom `Visualforce Tab` to replace it.

(1) If you want to take that route, first create the following `Visualforce Page`:

```
<apex:page tabStyle="Account">
    <apex:enhancedList type="Account" customizable="true" height="600" />
</apex:page>
```

---

(2) Next you need to create a `Custom Tab` for it. Go to `Setup` > `Create` > `Tabs`. In the `Visualforce Tabs` section, click <kbd>New</kbd>. Select the `Visualforce Page` you created from (1). Find the appropriate Icon. I would probably set the visibility to `Default Off`.

---

(3) You will now have two `Account` tabs, and so will want to hide the standard tab for all `Profiles`. To do so, go to `Setup` > `Manage Users` > `Profiles` > `[Select Profile]` > `Object Settings` > `Accounts`. Click `Edit` and change `Tab Settings` to `Tab Hidden`.

Comment: I remember doing this on Account and quickly discovered that I lost the OOB reports/wizards like 'Merge Accounts'

Comment: Ah of course. Certainly a disadvantage.